# Torch Cuda - Generates two processes on both GPU cores

Tags: luajit, torch

When I run;

```
require 'cutorch'
```

in lua it automatically allocates two processes to two of the cores in my GPU. For example I get the following output in `nvidia-smi`;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
|    1      6091    C   /home/msmith/torch/install/bin/qlua             98MiB |
|    2      6091    C   /home/msmith/torch/install/bin/qlua             99MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to be able to control which GPU the process goes on. I have tried;

```
cutorch.setDevice(<Device Number>)
```

but this just creates more processes on the GPU.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can control which GPU your process will run on *before* launching it using the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable, *e.g.* to run only on CPU 0:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
luajit your-script.lua
```

Comment: I ran this just before my iTorch notebook and it worked perfectly. Many CUDos

Comment: Just a remark that bit me: The id you use here is the one reported by CUDA deviceQuery (add +1 for cutorch.setDevice() as lua starts with 1 instead of 0). nvidia-smi can display a different  GPU id! Its super confusing...

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer said, choosing GPU can be done using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable on the command line before calling torch or torch-lua-script. This is a general way with CUDA and can be used with any application, not only torch. The number here can though clash with the number set in `cutorch.setDevice()` (also which instead is 1-based). One can select multiple specific GPU:s by a comma-separated list, for example:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1,2
```

This will result in torch running only on GPU 1 and 2. More information can be found here:

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/